# How to improve the center alignment of my TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm struggling with centering my sections and subsections to align to with my chapters. The chapters look like they are left of center (or everything else is right of center?).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

% TOC title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% TOC
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% Chapter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Section
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfillnum}[1]{\itshape\hspace*{10pt}\large#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionfont}{\itshape\large\hfil}

% Subsection
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\normalsize#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape\large\hfil}

% Spacing
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\subsection{Subsection Three}
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things at play.

1. You need to set `\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{0pt}` as it is making space for this and you are not using it
2. Use `\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\hfil\strut\par}`
3. We need to patch away a group bracing

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\l@chapapp}{{\cftchapterfont {#1}}\nobreak}{\cftchapterfont {#1}\nobreak}{\typeout{ok}}{\typeout{bad}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   otherwise the `\chapternumberline` trick and the title are linked in a manner that does not allow the text to center properly.

Comment: Worked perfectly. _/\\_